# "App not installed" error although apk is signed with the same upload key that signed previous release apk

Tags: android, apk

I built a new version of my app and tried to install apk on the previously installed app from the play store. But got error - "App not installed".
Shouldn't it get installed if both are signed with the same upload key?

Answer (score 0):

try to delete the Vir' device, and create an other one